# Cauchy's integral formula for a singular function

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Cauchy's integral theorem states that
$$\int_{\partial \mathbb{D}} f(z) \, d z =0 $$
for all functions $f$ that are holomorphic in $\mathbb{D} = \{|z| \leq 1\}$, i.e. no singularities are allowed in $\mathbb{D}$.

Here, $\partial \mathbb{D}$ denotes the boundary of $\mathbb{D}$ and hence $f$ is holomorphic along the path of integration.

Now my question regards functions of the form $f_\alpha(z) = \frac{1}{(1-z)^\alpha}$ where $0<\alpha<1$, which are only holomorph in the *open* disk $\{|z| < 1\}$.

Is Cauchy's theorem still applicable? I did some computations and it seems to hold true for $f_\alpha$. Is there a reference for a more general Cauchy theorem that allows (integrable) singularities along the path of integration?

Thanks!

Comment: You are right! As long as $\alpha <1$, everything is fine. The reason is, that the singularity at $z=1$ is integrable in this case. But be aware, that for $f_\alpha(z)=1/z^{\alpha}$, one has to take more care, because of the branch cut inside the domain of integration!

Comment: Thanks for our comment. But can you explain why Cauchy is still applicable? In all the definitions  I found on wikpedia or books, $f$ has to be holomorphic (i.e. complex differentiable, which implies continuity). But $f_\alpha$ is not continuous on the boundary of the disk.
Or do I have some misunderstanding of holomorphy?

Comment: I think Mr. Israel's answer should perfectly answer this question.

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ has a singularity at a point $p$ on the contour $\Gamma$, $\int_\Gamma f(z)\; dz$ may be undefined.  What is generally done is to deform the contour $\Gamma$ slightly to avoid $p$ and stay in the region where $f$ is holomorphic.
Cauchy's theorem, residues etc. can then be applied to the integral over the
deformed contour, and a limit taken as the amount of deformation goes to $0$.

Comment: Your argument would also apply to functions with non-integrable singlarities, i.e. poles. I do not understand why, without deformation of the contour, Cauchys theorem still holds true, even though there is an (integrable) singularity present on the contour.

Comment: I think the point is, that if a singularity is integrable you can just ignore it because you know it will contribute 0, and leave the procedure above implicit.