# Use the Cauchy Integral Formula to evaluate the following integral: $\int_C{\frac{z}{z^2+4z+3} dz}$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration, solution-verification

> I need to evaluate the following integral$$\int_C{\frac{z}{z^2+4z+3} dz}$$ where $C$ is the circle of centre $-1$ and radius $2$.

I found that $\frac{1}{z^2+4z+3}=-\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{z+3}-\frac{1}{z+1})$, $z=-3$ and $z=-1$ belongs to the circle and $f(z)=z$ is analytic on the complex plan. This leads me to

$$
\int_C \frac{z}{z^2+4z+3} dz
=-\frac{1}{2}\left(\int_C{\frac{1}{z+3} dz}
                  -\int_C{\frac{1}{z+1} dz}\right)
=2\pi i
$$

Comment: This isn't going to work since one of the singularities is on the path.

Comment: @paul any hint?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1321601/cauchys-integral-formula-for-a-singular-function

Comment: It's going to be undefined.